# jquery/js stop playing iframe video onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I go through couple of solution but none working. 
http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/2Lgxk5h3/1/

```
<iframe id="vd" type="audio/mpeg" width="420" autoplay="false" height="345" src="http://cache4.asset-cache.net/xd/468140002.mp4?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=72990B68305E4FDFEE95B69A879131BCD6D7111452E48A17C03F8342D660D5A451EBC1DEC2A827C9&b=RTdG" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
    //var url = $('#vd').attr('src');
    //$('#vd').attr('src', '');
    //$('#vd').attr('src', url);

    });
```

also

```
$('iframe').trigger('pause');
```

IDeally this should work, but still it is autoplaying. Please see I want to carry on with `iframe` only.

Answer (score 1):

After your page loads, you will run into your $(document).ready function

I think you could try setting the pause manually:

```
$('iframe').trigger('pause');
```

I have not tested it, but maybe you should give it a try.